# Setting up laravel on Centos server

Tags: laravel, centos6, mcrypt

Hi I have uploaded my files on the server. set up all permissions properly then when I try to run the app it returns an error message

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

Which is when I install php-mcrypt. it would output this message

```
Package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

anynone had this problem?

using centos5.8

Comment: 1.check inside your `php.ini` that the package is not just installed but also enabled. 2.restart php service.

Comment: As @Gal says, most likely you just need to uncomment the module in your php.ini, or add it to the list of modules if it isn't already in there.

Comment: I added extension=mcrypt.so on /usr/local/lib/php.ini and restart httpd still have the problem

Comment: what does phpinfo() show?

Comment: tried running phpinfo. shows complete list of modules. But no mcrypt. looks like something is wrong.

Comment: What does phpinfo show as the path to php.ini? Maybe you edited the wrong file?

Comment: this one. `/usr/local/lib/php` i only have one php.ini when I locate it

Comment: are you sure that `mcrypt.so` location is right ? also you need to restart php service